# copy to XPMode very slow

Tags: windows-xp-mode, file-transfer

When copying files (~1MB) from the host machine (W7 x64 Ultimate) to XPMode, the copy is very slow - ~8KB/s.

Copying the file to an actual network share (using explorer running on the host machine), then copying from the network share to the XPMode folder (using explorer running in XPMode) is quite fast.

Any ideas why this happens? And maybe even what can be done against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I found this, which seemed to work: (the registry change should be done on the host (Windows 7) machine, not the XP machine)
[Workaround for Windows VPC networking slowness between host and guest](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/3009f92b-05e2-481a-80ff-eca48c217204)

Then a coworker showed me how to disable this without the registry edit:
Start->Control Panel->Network and Sharing Center->Chagne Adapter Settings->Dbl-click 'Local Area Connection'->
Properties->Configure->Advanced-> Disable TCP Checksum Offload and UDP Checksum Offload (one each for IPv4 and IPv6)

This worked for me. I hope it helps you.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/3009f92b-05e2-481a-80ff-eca48c217204)

Comment: Hmm... that catapults me up to 36 KB/s...

Answer (score 1):

Since admintech's answer helped some, add these related commands to your try.

From an elevate command prompt run these:

> netsh interface tcp set global rss=disabled
>
> netsh interface tcp set global chimney=disabled
>
> netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037